# form multidimentional array from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I use **PHP 5.4** and **MariaDB 5.6**
I have one MYSQL table that contains records with the following:

network_id/size **|**  ip_group **|** ip **|** subnet_owner **|** subnet_location

I want to build a **multidimensional array directly from querying the database**, is it possible?
**Why do I need it?** I have checkboxes where if you check one IP, the checkbox should show up on the network_id/size and ip_group field. So I want to store them in layers, so I have to search through network_id/size only instead of going through all the records. Alternatively, if I check a whole network_id/size, I have instant access to all IDs.

- Every IP has an ip_group and a network_id/size
- groups are unique (there is no duplicate of IP and ip_group pair)

**I wish my array to look as follows:**
**network_id/size  =>(
ip_group =>(
ip
)))**

Also, I would like all the records to be identified with its id as I could easily sort it and look for, let's say, IP in a particular network_id/size and group directly using binary search.

If I cannot build the array directly, what would be the most efficient way to build such an array without using double for loops with (O)n^2 time complexity?

I thought about grouping by network_id/size, putting that into an array, then group by ip_group add that to every array that has matching network_id/size and then does the same with IP, query for all IP and adds it where a matching group is.

Comment: Essentially no. You would normally parse the flat array result using some kind of application cod, e.g. php, as mentioned